# Taurus pass fail criteria on throughput or transaction/hits per seconds

Tags: load-testing, jmeter-5.0, taurus

How should I add taurus pass-fail criteria if requests/second for a sampler are less than 10 TPS.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Pass/Fail Criteria](https://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/#Pass-Fail-Criteria) chapter of Taurus documentation

So if you add the following lines to your YAML configuration file:

```
reporting:
- module: passfail
  criteria:
  - hits<10 for 1s,stop as failed
```

Taurus will mark the test as failed if the throughput will be less than 10 TPS/second.

More information:

- [How to Run Your First JMeter Script in Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-jmeter)
- [Execute a Taurus Script with PassFail Configurations and PrePost Actions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6f3jvlJ-Gc)